# Find matching JSON items between 2 JSON arrays in JavaScript and apply CSS to matching items in a UL list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using JavaScript I need to take a JSON array of Tag items and generate an HTML UL list of all tags from that JSON data.

Next I have a 2nd JSON data-set of Tags in which I need to look in the first Tag JSON data and find each matching item between the 2 sets of tags.

When a Tag in the 2ns JSON data-set exist in the 1st Tag JSON data-set I need to add a CSS class to the UL list I generated from the 1st Tag data on each matching Tag

**1st JSON Tag Data-set**

```
var allTagsJson = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tag 1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Tag 2"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Tag 3"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Tag 4"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Tag 5"
}];
```

**2nd JSON Tag Data-set**

```
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tag 1"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Tag 4"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Tag 5"
}];
```

So in this sample data my UL list would have :

- Tag 1
- Tag 2
- Tag 3
- Tag 4
- Tag 5

As the 2nd JSON data-set has tags 1, 4, and 5.  The list above would need to add the CSS class `active` to tags 1, 4, and 5

JSFiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/tm9fsyvb/

```
var listTagsJson = [{

// generate 2 UL lists from JSON Data
$(function() {
    var allTagsHtml = '';

    // this list needs to add CSS class active to each item that has a matching tag in the 2nd list of tags
    $.each(allTagsJson, function(index, val) {
        console.log(val.name);
        allTagsHtml += " <li><a href='#" + val.name + "'>" + val.name + "</a></li>";
        $('#all-tags').html(allTagsHtml);
    });

    var listTagsHtml = '';
    $.each(listTagsJson, function(index, val) {
        console.log(val.name);
        listTagsHtml += " <li><a href='#" + val.name + "'>" + val.name + "</a></li>";
        $('#list-tags').html(listTagsHtml);
    });

});
```

Comment: do you need two list?

Comment: @charlietfl Your answer which you deleted works if I switch it around like this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/tm9fsyvb/

Comment: @JasonDavis right, I updated it to put it in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ID's  are only property that need comparing .... start with second array and while iterating it store each id as key in a hashmap object then check if it exists while iterating the first array  and add class accordingly

```
$(function() {
  // id object
  var listIds = {}

  var listTagsHtml = '';
  $.each(listTagsJson, function(index, val) {
    // add id to object
    listIds[val.id] = true;
    listTagsHtml += " <li><a href='#" + val.name + "'>" + val.name + "</a></li>";
  });

  var allTagsHtml = '';
  $.each(allTagsJson, function(index, val) { 
    // apply class based on id object
    var className = listIds[val.id] ? 'match' : '';
    allTagsHtml += " <li class='" + className + "'><a href='#" + val.name + "'>" + val.name + "</a></li>";
  });

  // note these don't belong inside the loops when using html string concatenation
  $('#all-tags').html(allTagsHtml);
  $('#list-tags').html(listTagsHtml);

});
```

This approach requires no additional dom searching or array filtering and is very efficient

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tm9fsyvb/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the second loop:

```
$("#all-tags").find("li").each(function(){
       if($(this).find("a")[0].innerHTML == val.name){
            $(this).addClass("active");
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a custom function to filter the matched elements form first array. If the element matches then add a class.

This snippet may be useful

```
//Rest of code
var listTagsHtml = '';
    $.each(listTagsJson, function(index, val) {
        // A custom function to check for the matched element
        // if it matches it will return a string(a custom class)
        var myClass=matchJson(val.id)
        // adding that class to li

        listTagsHtml += " <li class='"+myClass+"'><a href='#" + val.name + "'>" + val.name + "</a></li>";
        $('#list-tags').html(listTagsHtml);
    });



    //a function to check if it matches
    function matchJson(id){
        // using array filter function
        var filteredArray = allTagsJson.filter(function(a,b){
        return a.id ===id;
      })
      var toReturn = ''
      if(filteredArray !== undefined){
        toReturn ='customClass';
      }
      return toReturn;
    }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tm9fsyvb/3/)